# Should I add methods to my classes that inherit db.Model, or should I inherit those classes into a new class?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, models

When working with classes that inherit db.Model, is it better practice to add methods, or should I instead create a separate class?

E.g., if I want to store information on posts, should I have Post extend db.Model, or should I have PostData extend db.Model and Post extend (or even reference?) PostData?

The difference, I think, is that classes that inherit db.Model won't create instances without all the required attributes. The behaviour I'd like to see is not *saving* to the datastore without required attributes. Which is cleaner? Which is preferred?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding methods to `db.Model` subclasses is perfectly fine practice. There's only any point in having your actual model subclass something that is itself a `db.Model` subclass if you have common functionality you want shared by several model classes - just like in standard inheritance.

I'm not sure how your proposed approach would help with "not saving to the datastore without required attributes", unless you're planning on creating your own data models that you translate to and from datastore models - which is just going to be a huge waste of time (both yours and the processor's). The way the datastore library works, it's not possible to create a model with values that don't validate, and I'm not sure why you'd want to.

Answer (score 2):

Tip: use the business logic separated from the data store model

I think you should use your models as they are, in the purest form.

You can make other handlers to use those as explicit types. 
It is some cleaner not to inherit them. Just think to the data connection. You can use your models either in disconnected or in connected state.

In ruby I would use mixins or the concerned_with pattern on the models

In python I advice to use Django, so your views may contain the most part of the business logic. http://www.djangobook.com/en/1.0/chapter05/

**Try to use mixins!**

> A mixin class is a way of using the inheritance capabilities of classes to compose a class out of smaller pieces of behavior.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use composition (usually the better alternative to inheritance). e.g.

```
class MyModel(db.Model): pass

# Avoiding inheritance.
class MyWrapper(object):

  def __init__(self, my_model):
    # The leading _ indicates that methods in this class should
    # access self._my_model.
    self._my_model = my_model
```

Many would consider this to be unnecessary indirection, and I don't blame those people. Still, this might be good if you want to constrain `MyModel` instances in a way that the `validator` parameter in `db.Property` does not support. E.g.

```
class MyModel(db.Model):
  # f(x, y, z) = 0
  x = db.FloatProperty()
  y = db.FloatProperty()
  z = db.FloatProperty()
```

Enforcing the constraint without the help of `MyWrapper` is going to be harder.

Another reason to go with a wrapper is that you want to implement your own caching scheme, although `ndb` solves this in a more general way. When `MyModel` can only be manipulated through `MyWrapper`, then you can control what mutations are possible. Then, you can take care to invalidate cache entries as necessary.